# convert string to numbers and minus sign

Tags: bash, cut, string-conversion

I have a script with the following line in it:

```
cut -d" " -f$operation
```

`$operation` should be variable, so that it can be for example `1,6` so that cut extracts the first and sixth word of a string, or `2-5` extracting the second until the fifth word. However, this way this does not work out, I guess bash interprets the variable as one string. How can I write this correctly?

**Edit**

I am very sorry, this question is meaningless. I missed another error, that made the whole thing impossible to work.
Thanks to everybody wanting to help.

Comment: Seems to work fine on OSX and Linux; what OS, and how does it fail, and with what value of `$operation`?

Comment: You can start by showing us what input you're trying to process, and what exactly is the result you're seeing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for me it works in bash on Linux but you can try

```
cut -d" " -f"$operation"
```

to avoid parameter expansion. Are not there spaces?

Comment: I am so sorry, I did not see another error, that made the thing impossible to work. Thank you for your effort! I think i will delete the question.